# Have a subclass use a subclass

Tags: python-3.x, subclass

I have developed a generic `Environment` class which uses a generic `Agent` class within a `generic.py` file.
Now I'd like to create a `SpecificEnvironment` which uses a `SpecificAgent` within a `specific.py` file.

So far I got to specify (make specific) `Environment` with the following:

```py
from generic import Environment

class SpecificEnvironment(Environment):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

How do I get `SpecificEnvironment` to use a `SpecificAgent` subclass, instead of `Agent`?

Feel free to suggest some readings, so that I can educate myself.
I'm relatively new to object oriented programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a class attribute indicating which `Agent` subclass to use.

```
class Environment:
    EnvironmentAgent = Agent

    ...
```

You then need to replace every occurence of `Agent` in `Environment` by `self.EnvironmentAgent` or `cls.EnvironmentAgent` in class methods. This way if your subclass is provided a diffent `EnvironmentAgent` attribute, it will be used instead.

```
class SpecificEnvironment(Environment):
    EnvironmentAgent = SpecificAgent

    ...
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing. In the subclass you overwrite the `EnvironmentAgent` field. Also, this is the first time I see a use case for class attributes rather than an object ones. Just out of curiosity, is this the *standard way* of handling classes customisation? Meaning, having a generic template which is then specified? Tomorrow I'll try it out, and accept the answer if all works as expected!

Comment: Just tried. It's perfect. Now I'm just wondering whether there are more elegant solutions (*i.e.* how I should better design my software to do what I meant). But this solution is getting my simulator to work with customisations. Thanks!

Comment: I am fairly certain this is the most standard way to do. What you describe in your comment regarding class template really sounds like creating abstract base classes. Have a look at this module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html